# Did I flag incorrectly?

Tags: discussion, flags

I recently flagged a post as a duplicate because I do not have close vote privileges. The response from a moderator was:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of
>   content that requires their intervention

Apparently the post was closed as a duplicate after I flagged it as a duplicate. Maybe the moderator didn't see that?

I wasn't aware duplicates don't require moderator intervention. I don't have close vote privilege so I can't use close votes and the flag options don't allow me to mark it as a duplicate.

On another post, I flagged a post as "Primarily Opinion Based". Granted, I didn't use the "standard" flag for a post that is "primarily opinion based", I did use a flag. This was the response:

> declined - Please use standard close votes or flags for this.

What would have been the proper way to flag? If I see a low quality post, I am not presented with the same options as if I was in the Low Quality Queue.

We are always encouraged to flag for moderator attention if we see a problem. I don't think I was abusing the system.

Comment: You should be able to [flag to close as a dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). No moderator intervention is needed to close questions as dupes. "We are always encouraged to flag for moderator attention if we see a problem" if it is something that the community cannot handle ourselves.

Comment: @codeMagic: There was no option presented. If I recall, there were only a few options presented.

Answer (score 6):

You should be using the "it should be closed for another reason" option in the flag dialog whenever you encounter a duplicate or something that should be closed because it's off-topic, opinion based, broad, whatever. This sends them to the Close Votes queue rather than moderators, which lets the community handle it. We have a lot of other flags to deal with and close flags are usually just noise for us, especially duplicates since we can't always act on those unless we have experience in that area.

As far as your "primarily opinion based" flag - it shows that you previously *had* used the correct flag for that, and that it was declined because [all the reviewers chose to leave it open](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5239323). Attempting to flag it again will not allow the standard close option, because you can only use it once. But that certainly doesn't mean you should just cast an other flag. If you truly feel something is still close-worthy after your previous flag has been declined, you need to either provide more detail on why you believe that close reason fits, or you can come to Meta to get information on why it does or does not fit. Don't just cast a custom flag with the canonical close reason listed in it.

Comment: Understood, but I wasn't presented with an option to close for another reason.

Comment: My duplicate and opinion based flag were used on two different questions. When I flagged as a duplicate, I was not given the option to close for another reason. Did I miss something in your second paragraph? When I flagged the one question as opinion based again, I did it using the standard flags that was suggested and it was declined. This time, I assume, by the community based on what you are saying.

Comment: @staticx Looking at your duplicate flag, you submitted that flag a good three minutes after the question had already been closed. So no, the menu wouldn't have shown you that option because you can't close something that's already closed. Best advice: if you don't see the option you want, refresh the page.

Comment: Ok, I understand that now, but the interface should be improved. Perhaps a warning. At least it wouldn't waste everyone's time. If I recall correctly, the post didn't indicate it already was closed.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem, except I cast a recommend closure flag and the flag continued to remain unhandled after quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

> the flag options don't allow me to mark it as a duplicate

Yes they do.  You can flag a post using as specific category stating that the question should be closed (specifically, "it should be closed for another reason...").

Using a custom moderator flag for a question that should be closed is wrong, as the declined messages you have gotten indicate.

Comment: That option was not presented to me.

Comment: @staticx Then you had already cast a flag on that post (which appears to be the case here), or the post had already been closed.  That's the only reason it wouldn't be shown.

Comment: There was no indication it was closed.

Comment: @staticx Then you had already cast a flag on that post, instead of it having been already closed.  That, or it was closed after you loaded the page, and before you went to flag it.

Comment: It seems to be that it was closed before I flagged it but the post itself did not indicate it was closed either through some sort of AJAX type alert or in the flag dialog. At least it would helpful to improve the flag dialog to indicate this since it seems to already know it was closed because I couldn't choose that option. I now know that is the reason.

Comment: @staticx This is what it should be like: http://puu.sh/dd7ci/4e79f81c79.png#