# Flag for a duplicate post declined, but closed as duplicate

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I have a similar question as this one:
[Did I flag incorrectly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262896/did-i-flag-incorrectly)

But there is one big differents. His first problem is that he flagged a question as duplicate and was rejected, this is the same as I have. One of the answers was that he flagged to late and this is why it was declined.

I have flagged a question (because it was duplicate) already a week ago. Fifteen minutes later the question was closed because it was duplicate, but my flag wasn't accepted. At first I though, okay it can happen that they didn't see it so I'll wait. Few hours later I got my flag declined:

```
declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong. The only answers I could find are that people were to late, or just flagged for moderator without text. I did give the link in the text and said it was duplicate and/or low quality. And when I saw it was closed, I checked if my flag was indeed posted before it was closed, and this was the case.

Comment: Moderators are a busy lot. Very, *very* busy. Therefore, the community has to stand in for all the actions we can perform ourselves. That question required close votes, not flags.

Comment: Moderators should not be flagged in most of the daily clean-up we do unless something has gone *horribly, horribly wrong.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't flag the post to be closed as a duplicate, you used a custom moderator flag to say that the question should be closed.

It was correctly declined because you used the wrong type of flag.  Custom moderator flags should only be used for problems that *require* moderator attention, not issues that the community can resolve on its own.